# How to replace a string between two other strings

Tags: powershell

I am trying to replace in several files the following type of string:

*StringResourceHelper.[STRING_OF_INTEREST]ResourceString()*
with
*Strings.[STRING_OF_INTEREST]*

For example I would like to replace:

*StringResourceHelper.HelpResourceString()* with *Strings.Help*

So far, I got a simple replacement which would work if the second string would not be important:

```
    Get-ChildItem . *.cs -Recurse |
      Foreach-Object {
       $c = ($_ | Get-Content) 
       $c = $c -replace 'StringResourceHelper.','Strings.'
       $c | Set-Content $_.FullName -Encoding UTF8
    }
```

But this does not help me, because I also have Strings like *StringResourceHelper.Culture* which should not be touched.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape literal dots in your regular expression, otherwise `.` will match any character except newlines. Something like this should work:

```
$c = $c -replace 'StringResourceHelper\.(\w*?)ResourceString\(\)', 'Strings.$1'
```

Also, your code could be simplified a little, like this:

```
$srch = 'StringResourceHelper\.(\w*?)ResourceString\(\)'
$repl = 'Strings.$1'

Get-ChildItem . *.cs -Recurse | % {
   $filename = $_.FullName
   (Get-Content $filename) -replace $srch, $repl |
       Set-Content $filename -Encoding UTF8
}
```